# Python /Pandas INSERT dataframe into DB2 table using ibm_db

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, db2

While executing the code, nearly 50% of the total records are getting inserted. All of a sudden program stops with the mentioned errors

CODE:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect('DRIVER={IBM DB2 DRIVER};DATABASE=DEV;HOSTNAME=cloud.ibm.com;PORT=30000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=userid;pwd=password','','')
conni = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn)
subset = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5',
       'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9']]

tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in subset.values])

load_db2_sql = "INSERT INTO edw.DETAILS VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, load_db2_sql)

ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, tuple_of_tuples)
```

Error:

> Error 1064: Value parameters array 3386 is not homogeneous with
>   previous parameters array
>
> SQLCODE=-302 BM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0302N  The value of a
>   host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its
>   corresponding use.  SQLSTATE=22001

Comment: It seems like a data issue.  Can you provide an example (limited) data set which fails?  Most likely place to check is around the index of 3386 in `tuple_of_tuples`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe which I was trying to LOAD to DB2 table had 'nan' values.
I have replaced it with "No Value'. It worked after that.

```
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), 'No Value')
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and used Tad's code but instead of 'No Value' I used None.  It  inserted those Null "values" into the DB2 table.

`df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)`